# Why did Red Hat drop support for DRBD beginning with RHEL 7?

Tags: rhel, cluster, drbd

Does anybody know the reasons why Red Hat decided to drop support for DRBD beginning with RHEL 7, thus favoring GlusterFS as the preferred solution for network-based replication / mirroring in a cluster environment?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Red Hat never supported DRBD. However, they will support your services running on top of DRBD if you have a support agreement through LINBIT (creators of DRBD). 
 
Source: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/32085

Also, GlusterFS is developed by Red Hat. Which may be why it seems they prefer it.